# Topological interpretation of Compactness Theorem in propositional logic

Tags: general-topology, logic, propositional-calculus

Let $V$ be the set of truth valuations in propositional logic, and let $\Delta \subseteq PROP$. We define
$$[\Delta] = \{v \in V : v(\Delta)=1\}$$.
(If $\Delta =\varphi$, then we can write $[\Delta] =[\varphi]$).

I already know that the set
$$B =\{ [\varphi] : \varphi \in PROP \} $$
form a basis for a topology $\tau$ on $V$, and that the sets of the form $[\varphi]$ are clopen in $\tau$.

> The problem is: prove that the Compactness theorem for propositional logic is equivalent to the topological compactness of $(V,\tau)$.

There're also two hints:
(1) prove that the closed sets are exactly those of the form $[\Delta]$; (2) use the characterisation of topological compactness given in terms of closed sets.

Comment: What is your formulation for the compactness theorem for propositional logic?

Comment: Theorem: let $\Gamma \subseteq PROP$. Then $\Gamma$ is satisfiable iff every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable. ($\Gamma$ satisfiable means that $\Gamma \nvDash \bot$)

Comment: I tried to prove the first hint (I think I can manage it), but I don't understand how to use this hint in the proof of the equivalence

Comment: @FlaB: A topological space space $X$ is compact if and only if every [centred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property) system of closed sets in $X$ has non-empty intersection.

Answer (score 2):

> prove that the closed sets are exactly those of the form $[\Delta]$

Let $\Delta$ be a set of propositional formulae. We show that $V \setminus [\Delta]$ is open. In fact, $V \setminus [\Delta]$ may be expressed as the union of all $[\neg \phi]$ where $\phi$ belongs to $\Delta$: if $v$ is a valuation belonging to $[\neg \phi]$, then $v(\phi) = 0$ and so $v \notin [\Delta]$. Also, if $v \in V \setminus [\Delta]$, $v$ evaluates at least one formula $\phi \in \Delta$ as 0, and so $v$ belongs to $[\neg \phi]$. The sets $[\neg \phi]$, where $\phi \in \Delta$, are all open, so their union is open.

In the other direction, we have to show that if $X$ is a closed set of $V$, $X$ is of the form $[\Delta]$. $V \setminus X$ is open and is thus the union of a family of sets, each of which is $[\phi]$ for some formula $\phi$. (Here we have used the given base for $V$.) In other words, there is a set $\Gamma$ of formulae such that
$$V \setminus X = \bigcup_{\phi \in \Gamma} [\phi]$$
Define
$$\Delta = \{\neg \psi : \psi \in \Gamma\}$$
We claim that $[\Delta] = X$: if $v \in [\Delta]$, $v$ evaluates all formulae $\phi$ of $\Gamma$ as 0. Therefore $v \notin V \setminus X$. If $v \in X$, $v$ does not belong to any set $[\phi]$ for a formula of $\Gamma$. Therefore $v$ evaluates all formulae of $\Gamma$ as 0, so $v \in [\Delta]$.

> use the characterisation of topological compactness given in terms of closed sets

This characterisation is: every family of closed subsets of $V$ which satisfies the [finite intersection property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property) has a non-empty intersection. If $\Gamma$ is a set of formulae such that every finite subset of the family has a valuation which makes them all true, then
$$A = \{[\phi]: \phi \in \Gamma\}$$
is a family of closed subsets with the finite intersection property. The intersection of $A$, which, we know by compactness, is not empty, must therefore contain a valuation which satisfies all of $\Gamma$. Now that you have the idea, it should be straightforward to prove the other direction, namely that the compactness of propositional logic implies that $V$ is a compact space.